Is there a way to obtain KFunction from a Composable
As far as I know, function references to composable functions are not supported yet and so ::SomeComposable does not work. I am looking for a work around that lets me access the KFunction methods on composable functions.

Can you share a bit about what use case you are dealing with? Why do you need  to pass  a function reference to a composable?

What I am trying to do is have a composable take json string and another composable as parameters, and I want to have it call the composable in the parameter with the data from the json string. For this I needed to read the parameters of the composable
